# What name should I give these two classes which were split from one class?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, naming-conventions, naming

I recently did a refactoring. Basically, we have a system that reads an XML file and does some operations on it and then updates it and writes it out. I've split this functionality into two classes

1. A class which "controls" the XML and abstractly says what should be done with it
2. A class which handles everything with the XML and provides a simple interface for updating and reading what #1 is concerned about

The implementation is now significantly clearner. #1 doesn't have to worry about XML namespaces or XPath queries or any of that. It just says "hey #2, update this part from 'foo' to 'bar'".

However, I'm not for sure what to call it. The old class was named something my `FooManifestXml`. What should I call these two classes? I have some ideas, but I'd rather not skew the results.

Also, the big reason why I'm worrying about this simple naming is because more refactoring similar to this will probably be done in the future and I'd like to have some intuitive naming scheme for it

Comment: You are doing pretty well if your main problem is naming your classes ;) I personally would probably name them something like `FooManifestXmlController` and `FooManifestXmlHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like [Command pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern) with small changes.

*A class which "controls" the XML and abstractly says what should be done with it*

This can be an `ICommand`

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}
```

*A class which handles everything with the XML and provides a simple interface for updating and reading what #1 is concerned about*

This can contain implementation of actions:

```
public class UpdateCommand : ICommand
{
    private XML file;

    public UpdateCommand(XML file)
    {
        this.file = file;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        //omn nom nom xml
    }
}
```

And `main` may look like

```
XML file = new XML("file.xml");
ICommand updateCommand = new UpdateCommand(file);
updateCommand.Execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

At a high level I think of it this way:

### Storage:

- Filesystem
- Database
- Memory

With a crisp storage abstraction (**AbcStore** or **AbcRepository**) you can more easily add behavior like caching or locking.

### Serialization Format:

- XML
- JSON
- [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/)

Why did you choose XML, maybe that will change or maybe the data will be available in different formats for different clients. I don't know enough about your application to know if this makes sense.

I might name this abstraction **AbcSerializer**.

### Business Logic:

This is where you manipulate the data and **method names should be in the problem domain, not the solution domain.** What I mean by that is a method name should be something like `changeAddress` and not `updateChildNode`

Comment: This is expressly not a serializer, so this will not work. We read in an XML file and manipulate it a bit. Some parts of the XML must stay the same and we don't even have to know about them.